# agregar codigo en flutter

Tags: flutter

**necesito agregar el siguiente fragmento de codigo en flutter pero no he logrado hacerlo, necesito que el nuevo codigo quede en child expanded, he intentado adicionarlo pero me aparece error, si alguien puede colaborarme se lo agradecería, intente colocarlo y siempre me aparece errores , no se que etiquetas y componentes me faltan para poderlo estructurar y como seria :**

codigo actual:

```js
// THIS IS THE IMAGE I NEED TO LOOK BIG WHEN I CLICK
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ImageScreen(
        url: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
      ),
    ),
      ),
      child: Expanded(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          placeholder: (_, __) {
            return Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                radius: 15,
              ),
            );
//adicionar nuevo codigo
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

codigo que quiero agregar en el child Expanded debajo de la imagen :

```js
Text(
                                  '${_productosModel[index].name}',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 25,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '${_productosModel[index].price.toString()}COP',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                        right: 8.0,
                                        bottom: 8.0,
                                      ),
                                      child: Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                        child: GestureDetector(
                                          child: (!_listaCarro
                                                  .contains(item))
                                              ? Icon(
                                                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                                                  color: Colors.yellow[800],
                                                  size: 38,
                                                )
                                              : Icon(
                                                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                                                  color: Colors.red,
                                                  size: 38,
                                                ),
                                          onTap: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              if (!_listaCarro
                                                  .contains(item))
                                                _listaCarro.add(item);
                                              else
                                                _listaCarro.remove(item);
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se si entendí bien lo que quieres hacer, pero si en tal caso quieres apilar tus widgets, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => ImageScreen(
        url: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '?alt=media',
      ),
    ),
      ),
      child:Container(//height: 500, width: double.infinity
           child: Column(
             children: <Widget>[
               CachedNetworkImage(
                 imageUrl: '${_productosModel[index].image}' + '? 
                 alt=media',
                 fit: BoxFit.cover,
                 placeholder: (_, __) {
                 return Center(
                 child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                 radius: 15,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
       //todo el código que quieres agregar aquí debajo.
       ],
      );

   ),
```

francamente lo que estás haciendo es envolver tus widgets dentro de una columna para apilarlos, tambien podrias darle un tamaño al contenedor donde está la columna y si tienes bastantes hijos dentro de la columna podrias envolver la columna dentro de un SingleChildScrollView, no se si esto solucione tu problema.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda responder cuando se este seguro de la información que proporciona el OP, puedes dejar comentario para que confirme información. Revisar [answer], saludos.